# Selenium finding link by text when text-transform present

Tags: python, selenium

I have this HTML

```html
<div class="tabsAction">
  <a class="butAction" href="" title="" data-original-title="">Validar</a>
  <a class="butAction" href="" title="" data-original-title="">Copiar</a>
  <a class="butAction" href="" title="" data-original-title="">Convertir en plantilla</a>
  <a class="butActionDelete" href="" title="" data-original-title="">Eliminar</a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to select the Validar link.

```py
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Validar")
```

but selenium can't find it.

However if I do this:

```py
for link in links:
    print(link.text)
```

I get this:

```
VALIDAR
COPIAR
CONVERTIR EN PLANTILLA
ELIMINAR
```

I've checked and the class `.butAction` has a `text-transform: uppercase;` css.

I swear this 100% used to work just yesterday, why is it not working now? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `By.LINK_TEXT` it's better to use `By.XPATH`.
In this case you only need to know what text appears in the web element on the page, not how it presented to user.
This should work:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='butAction'][text()='Validar']")
```

Comment: I'll do that, it's so weird that it suddenly stopped working, I have a vague recollection of using uppercase the first time I wrote the script and having to change it.

Comment: I'm working as automation engineer for 8+ years and I don't remember if I ever used `By.LINK_TEXT`..

Answer (score 0):

I rarely use `By.LINK_TEXT` but I do remember a few times where it acts... odd in cases where the text is lowercase in the HTML but upper case on the page. Did you ever try all caps in your locator?

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "VALIDAR")
```